# Split Install API is not available. error code - 5 while installing dynamic feature Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, split, ondemand, dynamic-feature

I have published my .aab apks bundle to internal testing realease mode.

When i try to install dynamic feature on demand it give me exception:

```
com.google.android.play.core.splitInstall.SplitInstallException: 
Split Install Error(-5): Split Install API s not available.
```

I dont know why this API is not available why this error appears. Need help thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @matt any updates for solution of this error?

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was in the fact I had unloaded the dynamic feature module (for quicker build times) perhaps check that the feature you are trying to load is loaded in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Remember you have to add the dynamicFeatures also in the build.gradle of your application.

```
dynamicFeatures = mutableSetOf(":details")
```

See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/at-install-delivery#base_feature_relationship